# Completion Handler Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, syntax-error, completionhandler

I'm trying to make my own method with completion handler in Swift:

```
func callURL(url: NSURL, username: String, password: String, completionHandler: (NSData?) -> ()?) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let un = username
    let pass = password
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", un, pass)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    completionHandler(NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        return data
    })
}
```

But I get error on completion handler line:

```
'Void' is not convertible to 'NSData'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an `NSData` in a function returning `Void` (the NSURLConnection callback).

You should call the completionHandler within the NSURLConnection callback as it:

```
func callURL(url: NSURL, username: String, password: String, completionHandler: ((NSData?) -> Void)?) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let un = username
    let pass = password
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", un, pass)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        response, data, error in
        if let completion = completionHandler {
            completion(data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have Cannot convert the expression's type '(NSMutableURLRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue, (($T5, ($T5, $T6, ($T5, $T6, $T7) -> ($T5, $T6, $T7) -> $T4) -> ($T5, $T6, ($T5, $T6, $T7) -> $T4) -> $T4, ($T5, ($T5, $T6, $T7)...

Comment: I updated the code, because if you want your completion handler to be optional you have to declare as I did.